# How to simulate builtin 'unexpected kwarg' error?

Tags: python

Suppose that function `query` is defined like this:

```
def query(how='Here or there'):
    print 'Would you like them\n%s?' % how
```

Then, when the (invalid) expression

```
query(how='With a mouse', who='Daniel', where='Anywhere')
```

is evaluated, Python automatically emits the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/seuss.py", line 4, in <module>
    query(how='With a mouse', who='Daniel', where='Anywhere')
TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'who'
```

---

Now, suppose I need to define a function `reply` that takes zero or more positional arguments, as well as the optional named argument `prefix`.  IOW, all the expressions below should be valid, at least syntactically:

```
reply('in a box', 'with a fox')
reply('In a house', 'With a mouse', preamble='I would not like them\n')
reply(preamble='I do not like them, Sam-i-am.')
```

The only way I know to implement such a function, is with the signature `(*args, **kwargs)`; unfortunately, with this signature, invalid expressions like `reply('green eggs', wot='and', wotelse='ham')` are fine as far as Python is concerned, which means that we have to do that error-checking ourselves.

Since such error-checking is pretty formulaic and tedious, it makes sense to refactor it into its own separate module.  For example<sup>1</sup>:

```
# check.py

def unexpected_kwargs(kwargs):
    unexpected = kwargs.keys()
    if len(unexpected) > 0:
        import inspect
        caller = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe(1)).function
        raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" %
                        (caller, unexpected[0]))
```

### EDIT: For the sake of this question, please take such factoring-out of the error-handling code as a **given**.

Now we can implement `reply(*args, **kwargs)` like this:

```
import check

def reply(*args, **kwargs):

    preamble = kwargs.pop('preamble', 'Not ')
    check.unexpected_kwargs(kwargs)

    # rest of function definition
```

...and the evaluation of `reply('green eggs', wot='and', wotelse='ham')` results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/seuss.py", line 14, in <module>
    reply('green eggs', wot='and', wotelse='ham')
  File "/tmp/seuss.py", line 9, in reply
    check.unexpected_kwargs(kwargs)
  File "/tmp/check.py", line 8, in unexpected_kwargs
    (frameinfo.function, unexpected[0]))
TypeError: reply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wot'
```

This looks similar to the error output shown earlier, but note that in that output, the offending line (`query(how='With a mouse', who='Daniel', where='Anywhere')`) was printed at the very end of the traceback, whereas in the second output the offending is printed several lines above.  The rest of the traceback, after the offending line, is IMO unnecessary noise that only serves to obscure the error responsible for failure.

IOW, to *really* replicate Python's handling of unexpected keyword, the error output should look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/seuss.py", line 14, in <module>
    reply('green eggs', wot='and', wotelse='ham')
TypeError: reply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wot'
```

Of course, one wrong way to achieve this would like this:

```
def unexpected_kwargs_NO_GOOD(kwargs):
    unexpected = kwargs.keys()
    if len(unexpected) > 0:
        import inspect
        import traceback
        import sys

        print >> sys.stderr, ('Traceback (most recent call last):\n%s' %
                              ''.join(traceback.format_stack()[:-2])),

        frameinfo = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe(1))

        print >> sys.stderr, ('TypeError: '
                              "%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" %
                              (frameinfo.function, unexpected[0]))
        sys.exit(1)
```

This produces the right-looking output, but it does not raise a exception that upstream code can trap.  Instead, it terminates the program's execution unconditionally.

Is there a way to do get the desired output, and at the same time raising a proper exception?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> One could factor out more of the arguments handling than just the error handling, but since this additional functionality is tangential to the post's question, I kept it out of the sample code above.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't raise the exception at the exact same point Python raises it, no. Just raise an exception when there are more keyword arguments than you can handle.

That *should* be fine; all information to debug the incorrect function call is present in the traceback still.

Comment: Please assume that the error-checking code has been factored out to a separate module.  I realize that this is not necessary in the simple example given in the question's statement, but in what I'm doing such factoring out of the error checking code is desirable.

Comment: @kjo: so? That should still just raise the exception.

Comment: If what I want to do can't be done, then please just say so.  That would be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: That's what I say at the top :-)

Comment: @kjo: sorry, I'm doing too many things at once on the fly. I've toned it down a little.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know exactly which keyword arguments you want to accept, then you don't want to use `**kwargs` at all.  You just want to use plain old keyword arguments.

It seems like you're searching for a feature which was added in Python 3 (see [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)) to support "keyword-only" arguments: arguments that will never be automatically filled in by a positional argument.

```
>>> def reply(*args, preamble='Not '):
...     print(args)
...     print(preamble)
...     
>>> reply('arg1', 'arg2')
('arg1', 'arg2')
Not 
>>> reply('arg1', 'arg2', preamble='yeah')
('arg1', 'arg2')
yeah
>>> reply('arg1', 'arg2', preamble='yeah', wot='wat')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b16c25a18626> in <module>()
----> 1 reply('arg1', 'arg2', preamble='yeah', wot='wat')

TypeError: reply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wot
```

What you want is not possible in Python 2.  The usual pattern in Python 2 code is just to use `**kwargs`, and **clearly document the accepted options in the docstring**.  Usually we just ignore any spurious arguments sent in, they don't raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

I disapprove all of this prototype checking and argument magic because it violates the KISS principle, however I think there is a way to implement (almost) the exact behavior you want:

```
def reply(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        my_arg_check(args, kwargs, *other_parameters)
    except MyArgCheckFailure as exc:
        raise TypeError(exc.my_custom_message)
```

Comment: Nothing is doing type checking here. I'm not sure that converting one exception into another is answering the question either.

Comment: But there are no other options, not in Python 2, to accept both positional arguments *and* specific keyword arguments.